# Vue 2 - how to calculate total from v-models integer values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i am using nuxt 2.8.1

i have 100 inputs. All inputs are number

i want to calculate in sum all number to get total

i tried this

```
computed: {
     total() {
       return this.form.one + this.form.two
     }
}
```

## what i expected

> 5 + 5 = 10

## what output getting

> 5 + 5 = 55

if i don't put value in two
result `5null`

i don't understand why its

Comment: use: parseInt(this.form.one) + parseInt(this.form.two)

Comment: right now you're obviously concatenating strings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It considers them like strings and concatenates them like you see, so you should use a `Number` object to cast them to integers like :

```
 return Number(this.form.one) + Number(this.form.two)
```

to be more efficient i recommend to use `reduce` function since you're having multiple inputs :

```
 return Object.values(this.form).reduce((a,c)=>{
       return a+Number(c);                 
       },0)
```

Example :

```js
let form = {
  one: 45,
  two: 5,
  three: 7
}

let sum = Object.values(form).reduce((a, c) => {
  return a + Number(c);
}, 0)

console.log(sum)
```

Comment: you're welcome, check my updated answer where i put a good tip to deal with your situation

Comment: i am getting undefine when i use reduce methods

Answer (score 0):

Since your param is a form, i guess this is related to user input. Then you could also solve it with a modifier (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number)

HTML

```
<input v-model.number="form.one" ></input>
<input v-model.number="form.two" ></input>
```

JS (same as it was before, or with the reduce method)

```
computed: {
     total() {
       return this.form.one + this.form.two
     }
}
```